# What to use instead of JQuery val() for value

Tags: jquery, html

I need to get the values 1 or 2 from the divs if they are pressed. I have made a script to set either to active when pressed, but I cannot seem to find out how to extract the value 1 if the first div is pressed. The HTML value attribute is only for input elements and in this case I want it on a div. How is this possible?

**Example**

```
<div class="booking_search_cat darkgrey active">
    <p>Group room</p>
</div>
<div class="booking_search_cat lightgrey">
    <p>Lecture room</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see 1 or 2 in your html. Where do you expect that to come from? the div's index?

Comment: Why not use a button? Buttons are clickable DOM elements which have value attributes?

Comment: I would not expect the value to come flying in, however the attribute value="someval" is not valid for divs.

Comment: I'm glad to see you accepted my answer (thanks!), however I feel that my [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16196998/558021) might just be a better technique :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply add a `data-*` attribute to the categories:

```
<div class="booking_search_cat darkgrey active" data-category="1">
    <p>Group room</p>
</div>
<div class="booking_search_cat lightgrey" data-category="2">
    <p>Lecture room</p>
</div>
```

Now all you have to do is extract that info on the click event.

```
$('.booking_search_cat').on('click',function(){
  var categoryId = $(this).data('category');
  console.log(categoryId);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
<div class="booking_search_cat darkgrey active" data-value='group_room'>
  <p>Group room</p>
</div>

<div class="booking_search_cat lightgrey" data-value='lecture_room'>
  <p>Lecture room</p>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  var $booking_search = $(".booking_search_cat");

  $booking_search.click(function(){
    $booking_search.filter(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

    alert("The value is "+$(this).data("value"));
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `data-val` attribute. [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6575r/1/).

```
<div class="booking_search_cat darkgrey active" data-val='1'>
    <p>Group room</p>
</div>
<div class="booking_search_cat lightgrey" data-val='2'>
    <p>Lecture room</p>
</div>

$(".booking_search_cat").click(function(){
    alert($(this).data('val'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the data attribute

```
<div data-val="1" ...
```

and

```
$(".bookingsearch").on("click",function() {
  $.post("someserverthing",{parm:$(this).data("val")},function(data) {
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `index()` function to determine which element was clicked -

```
$('.booking_search_cat').on('click',function(){
  var categoryId = $(this).index('.booking_search_cat');
  console.log(categoryId);
});
```

The `index()` function returns (as the name states) the index of the element. The documentation has this to say about the return value -

> If a selector string is passed as an argument, .index() returns an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to the elements matched by the selector. If the element is not found, .index() will return -1.

#### [Here is a *very* simple demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tchuh/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) in your `click` handler to determine which (in the order of DOM nodes) was clicked:

```
$('.booking_search_cat').on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).index('.booking_search_cat')); // 0 if first was clicked, 1 if second was clicked, etc.
});
```

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mU9T4/2/)

EDIT: As pointed out by Lix, `.index()` needs a selector so as to ignore siblings when computing the index. Demo link updated.

Comment: You need to give a selector to the index function other wise it will take into consideration all sibling elements and not just the `.booking_search_cat` elements.

Comment: @Lix Thanks, didn't catch that `.index()` could accept selectors to effectively ignore siblings. Given that, I'm leaning towards the `data` method as outlined in other answers as a more effective solution instead of this.